# Runtime change the language/localization in Three20

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, three20

Is it possible to change the Three20 language/localization at runtime without restarting the app?

Currently, I managed to change the language via altering the value of `AppleLanguages` in the main.m

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a "hack" for it. You can load your own NSBundle with the localized text and use that NSBundle instead. Note that if the localized language file is missing, the app won't run, so make sure you set a correct language.

Above your AppDelegate implementation, add a custom NSBundle declaration:

```
static NSBundle *bundle = nil;
```

And then load the language you desire into that bundle:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"he", nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];

NSLocale* locale = TTCurrentLocale();  
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[locale localeIdentifier] ofType:@"lproj" ];
bundle = [[NSBundle bundleWithPath:path] retain];
```

You will add a custom function in your AppDelegate to get the localized text too (instead of   NSLocalizedString)

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
+ (NSString*)get:(NSString*)key  {
   return [bundle localizedStringForKey:key value:nil table:nil];
}
```

To make things easier, you can add a static function in the pch file:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#define MyLocalizedString(key, alt) [AppDelegate get:key]
```

Comment: Where do I put the second block of code of your answer?  In my app delegate?  And what would I put in my "changeLanguageToSpanish" button?

Comment: is the answer still relevant?